# Fail to resolve ip address

Tags: 14.04, networking, network-manager

I tried to diagnose internet problem myself

ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f8:a9:63:3f:9e:97  
  UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
  RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
  TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
  collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
  RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
  Interrupt:16 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
  inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
  inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
  UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
  RX packets:185 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
  TX packets:185 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
  collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
  RX bytes:13343 (13.3 KB)  TX bytes:13343 (13.3 KB)
```

I see no resolved IP address under eth0, so I tried to edit /etc/network/interfaces file

add line

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

now it contains

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

after restart the service by

```
sudo service networking restart
```

The eth0 item in output of ifconfig is totally gone

now

ifconfig

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
  inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
  inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
  UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
  RX packets:185 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
  TX packets:185 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
  collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
  RX bytes:13343 (13.3 KB)  TX bytes:13343 (13.3 KB)
```

How is this supposed to be happened ?

Comment: Just to make sure - do you have dhcp server in your network?

Comment: @Jacek thanks for your response. I am not sure if it is running. How can I check it? thanks

Comment: Well - whoever manages your network should really know. If it's a hope network with your broadband modem - I'd say you should have dhcp running, but who knows. Anyway - can you try to run dhclient command to see what it tells?

Comment: @Jacek it is empty output

Comment: So you may have no dhcp server in your network - if that's true, using dhcp setting in your interfaces configuration is pointless. In such a case you'll need rather to set static IP.  Who manages your network?

Comment: @Jacek thank you very much for your help. The problem is solved :)

Comment: Hello lad: what exactly solved your problem (post here in the comments) @Jacek Convert it into an answer so that people like me don't go hunting for unanswered questions to see it resolved in the comments!  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that lack of dhcp server may be a problem here. In such a case you will need to setup static IP in interfaces (make sure about dhcp with whoever manages the network)

iface eth0 inet **dhcp**

dhcp means that interface should look for dhcp server which will assign IP to it.

And if there's no dhcp server in the network something like this may be needed:

iface eth0 inet **static**
address 192.168.1.50
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1

These are just examples - all depends on actual network.

If unsure whether you have dhcp in your network or not - you can try to run dhclient command which will try to assign IP from dhcp to your interface. If there's no result - there's apparently no dhcp in your network or it may not work properly.

I hope that will help at least to diagnose the problem a bit.